# EcmaScript - Глобальная переменная внутри класса

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript

Всем добрый вечер! Скажите пожалуйста есть ли какая возможность сделать глобальную переменную внутри функций ES6 класса? Например передать $scope и $http всем функциям что внутри класса. То-есть фактический избавиться от this.$scope = $scope и this.$http = $http и.т.д. Что-бы в каждой функции была переменная $scope и $http без this.

```
import {AngularController} from '../core/AngularController';

class XCustomPageController extends AngularController {

  static $inject = ['$scope','$http'];

  constructor($scope, $http) {
    super($scope)
    $scope.name = "Input new name and click `Set` button"
  }

  setNewNameButtonClick(event) {
    this.$scope.name = event.target.value;
  }

}

export default {XCustomPageController};
```

Comment: речь точно про javascript, а не про typescript? В любом случае - пока это нельзя сделать. Доступ к полям класса только через `this`, либо `super`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока такой возможности нет.

---

Доступ к полям класса только через `this`, либо `super`. Поэтому, если параметры сохранять в поля класса, доступ к ним будет только при использовании `this`.

Однако, **если предоставленный класс используется как Singleton**, параметры можно сохранять во внешние переменные:

```
import {AngularController} from '../core/AngularController';

var $scope, $http;

class XCustomPageController extends AngularController {

  static $inject = ['$scope','$http'];

  constructor(scope, http) {
    super(scope)
    $scope = scope;
    $http = http;

    $scope.name = "Input new name and click `Set` button"
  }

  setNewNameButtonClick(event) {
    $scope.name = event.target.value;
  }

}

export default {XCustomPageController};
```

Но корректно это будет работать *только* если будет создано не больше одного экземпляра.

Comment: Вот идея с внешними переменными очень неплохо смотрится как решение, просто достался проект где какой-то странный человек в каждый контроллер написал this.$scope = $scope... А AngularController по сути просматривает все функции класса и переносит их в $scope... $scope[funcName] = func; что по сути своей тоже весьма топорный вариант... Хочется простого и красивого решения...